# Dynamically generate and/or output a XSL variable where the variable name is stored as a string in another variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSL 1.0. Currently there is no possibility to use 2.0

I have a variable `$myVar` and I have a variable name `'myVar'` stored as a string in another variable `$refName = 'myVar'`. Can I somehow output the content of `$myVar` variable using xsl:value-of and `$refName` which contains the variable name as a string?

Basically I need to dynamically generate a variable name `'$myVar'` in the select attribute of xsl:value-of out of the text stored in another variable `$refName`.

I would like something like `${$refName}` to behave like `$myVar`. I'm stuck. Tried everything.

Normally I would output a variable like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="/ns1:root/ns1:node" />
<xsl:value-of select="$myVar" />
<!-- OUTPUTS: Content of /ns1:root/ns1:node -->
```

**This is what I want (It doesn't work):**

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="/ns1:root/ns1:node" />
<xsl:variable name="refName" select="'myVar'" />
<xsl:value-of select="${$refName}" />
<!-- ERROR, GOAL OUTPUT: Content of $myVar, Content of /ns1:root/ns1:node -->
```

---

Or even more complicated my concrete issue. I would like to dynamically output all defined XSL variables. I need a function such as `load-node-from-query-string()`, or `parse()` or similar.

Is there any possibility to output all XSL variables or a XSL variable when you have its name, and select query stored an another variable as a string?

```
<xsl:for-each select="document('')//xsl:variable">
    <xsl:variable name="ref_name" select="./@name" />
    <xsl:variable name="ref_select" select="./@select" />

    <xsl:value-of select="$ref_name" />
    <!-- OUTPUTS: Variable name e.g. myVar -->

    <xsl:value-of select="$ref_select" />
    <!-- OUTPUTS string of select attribute e.g. '/ns1:root/ns1:node' -->

    <xsl:variable name="ref_value" select="load-node-from-query-string($ref_select)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$ref_value" />
    <!-- ERROR, GOAL OUTPUT: Content of /ns1:root/ns1:node -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You could try and use an extension function to do dynamic evaluation (See http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/) but this won't be effective if the variable uses a relative path (i.e. `<xsl:variable name="test" select="child" />`, as you won't have any current context. Additionally, xsl:variable statements don't even need a select and can have complex statements nested inside them. Also, if you are just reading the XSLT document itself, why don't you just stick `xsl:value-of` statements after each `xsl:variable` statement in the XSLT if you want to see the value? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @TimC for the comment. I was just wondering if this can be done easily. I guess I would go with xsl:value-of statements after each xsl:variable statement as you suggested